# how can send text fields data from iphone to server through xml parsing file in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml-parsing

I am new to iphone development. I have some doubt in how can I send data from iPhone app to server with xml parsing ...how can I append text fields data into xml file and how can I send that xml file with text fields data to server

I searched a lot in google but I can't get some idea please give some more idea about how can append textfields data into xml

can you please give me related soucre code or  related linkes for quite from dz problem

my xml format like as

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <id/>
        <msg>0</msg>
        <name/>
        <country/>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825605/create-xml-file-dynamically-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Use this open source xml writer https://github.com/skjolber/xswi

```
    XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Users"];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"User"];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"id"];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourtextfield.text]];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"name"];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"country"];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];

    NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own `xml` as a `NSString` and pass it to the web service. Which solves your problem.

```
NSString *strXML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"                                      <TemplateId>%@</TemplateId>\
                                           <ProjectName>%@</ProjectName>\
                                           <SizeId>%d</SizeId>\
                                           <Quantity>%d</Quantity>\
                                           <TotalAmount>%0.2f</TotalAmount>\", dataModel.ProjectId,dataModel.ProjectName, [dataModel.templateSizeId intValue], dataModel.projectQuantity,[dataModel.templateAmount floatValue]];
```

Comment: thanks for quickly replay ...but how can create xml file by own

Comment: I edited my answer to create xml as a string please chk it & let me know if u have any problem in it.

Comment: actully php peoples are create xml file ...in my code i need use that url and i need append my textfields into xml file and send server...

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833061/modify-attribute-of-xml-tag-in-objective-c/13835765#13835765 my answer which help you.